# How to clear console warning when entering mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

I am using **Mongo DB 3.6.4**.

When I use command mongo then we get lot of warnings as below

```
emgda@emgda:/var/log/mongodb$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.4
Server has startup warnings:
2019-11-29T10:30:39.069+0530 W COMMAND  [conn20] the eval command is deprecated
2019-11-29T11:03:14.285+0530 W COMMAND  [conn21] the eval command is deprecated
2019-11-29T11:35:20.590+0530 W COMMAND  [conn18] the eval command is deprecated
2019-11-29T12:07:58.073+0530 W COMMAND  [conn24] the eval command is deprecated
```

How can we remove the console warning? is it logged somewhere? so that when I clear logs, it must not give these warnings next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eval` command has been deprecated since MongoDB 3.0 and was [removed in MongoDB 4.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#remove-support-for-the-eval-command). This warning is issued to allow administrators to track usage of the command and ideally replace with something more efficient.

The `eval` command has serious [performance, scalability, and security consequences](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/command/eval/#behavior):

- **Write lock**: By default, `eval` takes a global write lock while evaluating the JavaScript function. As a result, `eval` blocks all other read and write operations to the database while the `eval` operation runs.
- **Access Control**: If authorization is enabled, you must have access to all actions on all resources in order to run `eval`.
- **Sharded Data**: You can not use `eval` with sharded collections.

> How can we remove the console warning? is it logged somewhere?

If you want to suppress this (and all other) startup warnings when starting the `mongo` shell, you can use `mongo --quiet`.

To resolve the warnings permanently you need to remove usage of `eval` from your client applications.